# PHP check if record exist in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to check if record exist in SQL and get a return -> True or False.
It returns a notice:
*Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in....*  if($result->num_rows > 0)

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass','db_name');
$query = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE telephone = '".$telephone."' AND order_status_id='0' ";

$result = $connection->query($query);
            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo 'found'; // The record(s) do exist
                }
            else{
                    echo 'not found'; // No record found
                }

    $connection->close();
```

Comment: check first `$result` value. use `print_r($result)` to check the value.

Comment: `ORDER` is a mysql reserved word.

Comment: You query fails because `order` is `reserved keyword` in mysql it must be in backtick https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Apart from using the reserved word, why are you closing the connection at the end of your script?

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` is a [mysql reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Using it as field name, table name or whatever except `ORDER BY fieldname` requires using backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE ....
```

Otherwise, you will get a query error, which will turn `$result` into boolean **false**.

Also, your code is vulnerable to [sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).
I advise you to use **prepared statements**.

Comment: As a small tip to add, if you want to still use "order" as tablename but don't want to "escape" it each time, you can follow name convention and user plural : "orders"

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the rows of the query object. The query object does not contain the rows.

What you want to do is something like

```
$data = $result->fetch_array();
if ($data->num_rows > 0)
{
    //Rows exist
} else {
    //No rows exist
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It happens in case query do not injects object in your `$result` variable. You can make the following changes to proceed.

```
if(is_object($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo 'found'; // The record(s) do exist
} else{
     echo 'not found'; // No record found
}
```

**OR**

```
if(!empty($result->num_rows)) {
         echo 'found'; // The record(s) do exist
    } else{
         echo 'not found'; // No record found
    }
```

Also keep the thing simple:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE telephone = '$telephone' AND order_status_id='0' ";
```

Comment: Your query fails because order is reserved keyword and must be in backtick

Comment: Great! You are great! No error, but returns only result of ELSE. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your `$result` gets the expected results? I do not think so, please share your `$result` contents?

Answer (score -3):

```
Use like this

 $sqlReq = " SELECT * FROM order WHERE telephone = '".$telephone."' AND order_status_id='0' ";

                $queryReq = mysql_query($sqlReq) or die(mysql_error());

                if(mysql_num_rows($queryReq) > 0)
                {
                    echo "found";
                 }else{
                     echo "not found";
                       }
```